# How to create a nested array using Json and each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is the code How can create nested array here how to pus array it self. What is the code  i can use for this.push because it does not work.....

```
function getAddedItemDetailArray() {
    debugger;
    var arrItemDetail = [];
    $(".clsaddNewItem").each(function () {
        arrItemDetail.push({
            "itemid": $(this).find(".clsHdfSitemId").val(),
            "uomid": $(this).find(".clsUom").val(),
            "orderqty": $(this).find(".clsOrderQuantity").val(),
            "deliveringqty": $(this).find(".clsDeliveringQuantity").val(),
            "listofgoodsdeliverynoteitemmapallocation": [$(this).find(".clsaddNewItemSub").each(function() {
                **this**.push({

                    "itemwarehousedetailmapid": $(this).find(".clsLocation").val(),
                    "qty": $(this).find(".clsQty").val()

                })
            })]


        })
    });
    return arrItemDetail;
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE in a [mcve] - you have a snippet, add the rest of the relevant HTML

Comment: You need to move `[$(this).find(".clsaddNewItemSub").each(function() {.....push({

                    "itemwarehousedetailmapid": $(this).find(".clsLocation").val(),
                    "qty": $(this).find(".clsQty").val()
` outside the other loop or use map

Comment: add html code here

Comment: When i move  all ```function getAddedItemDetailAllocationArray() {
    debugger;
    var arrItemDetailAllocation = [];
    $(".clsaddNewItem").find(".clsaddNewItemSub").each(function () {
        arrItemDetailAllocation.push({
            
            "itemwarehousedetailmapid": $(this).find(".clsLocation").val(), 
            "qty": $(this).find(".clsQty").val()
           
        })
    });
    return arrItemDetailAllocation;

  
}
``` like this it get all sub row array it does not get each of line sub arrays

Answer (score 1):

Javascript this scope is referring to different object when inside of a function. You can read more about `this` and scope over [MDN documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

To solve the problem, I suggest you use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to replace the inner anonymous function to retain the scope to access the correct `this`.

```js
 


function getAddedItemDetailArray() {
    debugger;
    var arrItemDetail = [];
    $(".clsaddNewItem").each(function () {
        arrItemDetail.push({
            "itemid": $(this).find(".clsHdfSitemId").val(),
            "uomid": $(this).find(".clsUom").val(),
            "orderqty": $(this).find(".clsOrderQuantity").val(),
            "deliveringqty": $(this).find(".clsDeliveringQuantity").val(),
            "listofgoodsdeliverynoteitemmapallocation": [$(this).find(".clsaddNewItemSub").each( () => {
                this.push({
                    "itemwarehousedetailmapid": $(this).find(".clsLocation").val(),
                    "qty": $(this).find(".clsQty").val()
                })
            })]


        })
    });
    return arrItemDetail;
}
```

Comment: **this.push** is not a function you can not use like this

Comment: I would expect something like `[$(this).find(".clsaddNewItemSub").map( () => {
               return {
                    "itemwarehousedetailmapid": $(this).find(".clsLocation").val(),
                    "qty": $(this).find(".clsQty").val()
                }})`